# Checking latency between client and host

Tags: networking

The user is complaining about uploading a 1.2 GB file from China Shangai to our data center in Japan Tokyo is taking more than 1 hour.But when I try to upload the file from the USA West it's faster and takes 1 minute.I am thinking it might be latency issue and also user has a BandWidth of 16-17 Mbps

How to perform latency test.I can ask the user to run latency test to my servers and conclude its latency issues.

I know it's more generic question but is there any way we can improve this upload performance?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ping` and compare last your and your customer columns: 
Here is an example of ping result from 2 different servers:
First one has 17.3 ms
`64 bytes  (173.194.222.113): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=17.3 ms`
The second one 9.35 ms
`64 bytes  (216.58.217.206): icmp_req=1 ttl=58 time=9.35 ms`